# Inherit generic value from object property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given the following generic type is there any way to inherit the `Props` type from the required `component` property without having to pass `Props` to `Override`?

```js
type Override<Props extends {} = {}> = {
  component: React.ComponentType<Props>
  props?: Props
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following

```js
type AnchorProps = { [...] }
const Anchor: React.ComponentType<AnchorProps> = [...]
type ParagraphProps = { [...] }
const Paragraph: React.ComponentType<ParagraphProps> = [...]

type Overrides = {
  // i want to do this
  [tag in keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]?: Override

  // rather than this
  a: Override<AnchorProps>,
  p: Override<ParagraphProps>,
  [...]
}

const overrides: Overrides = {
  a: {
    component: Anchor, // type is now `React.ComponentType<AnchorProps>`
    props: { [...] },  // type should inherit from `component` and be `AnchorProps`
  },
  p: {
    component: Paragraph, // type is `React.ComponentType<ParagraphProps>`
    props: { [...] },     // type should inherit `ParagraphProps`
  },
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a full example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I've updated the question

Comment: The problem is, that as far as I can tell there is no relation between `JSX.IntrinsicElements.a` and `AnchorProps`. On what basis could we make this association. Without an extra type to map between the `a` and `AnchorProps` or a single module exporting all components, and some extra type info on each to allow us to create a relation between the `a` and `AnchorProps` there is no way to automate the creation of  `Overrides`

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot inherit the `Props` type from the `component` type. This just isn't something that's possible with TypeScript

You also can't do this directly if you are using custom interfaces for `AnchorProps` and `ParagraphProps` instead of the standard `React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>` and `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>`

However, if your `Anchor` component takes the same props that the standard `HTMLAnchorElement` does, it is possible to achieve your desired result with only a few lines.

```ts
declare const Anchor: React.ComponentType<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>
declare const Paragraph: React.ComponentType<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>

type Overrides = {
  [tag in keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]?: {
    component: React.ComponentType<JSX.IntrinsicElements[tag]>,
    props?: JSX.IntrinsicElements[tag]
  }
}

const overrides: Overrides = {
  a: {
    component: Anchor,
    props: {
      href: 'str', // ok
      broken: true // error, as expected
    }
  },
  p: {
    component: Paragraph
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell TypeScript what is the relation between an intrinsic element and your custom props.

```
interface OverriddenProps extends JSX.IntrinsicElements {
  a: AnchorProps;
  p: ParagraphProps;
}
```

Create your `Overrides` mapped type:

```
type Overrides = {
  [Tag in keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]?: {
    component: React.ComponentType<OverriddenProps[Tag]>;
    props: OverriddenProps[Tag]
  }
}
```

The type inference will now work correctly.